# mock Axios.Create() in unit testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, axios

i want to create an unit testing for my service. In my service, i used axios.create function to help me configure some config. I am a little confused with the unit test.
I've done creating unit tests and mocks for axios but without using axios.create. Maybe you can help me to solve my problem. I have tried several solutions but have not been able to solve my problem

this is my api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;


const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json"
  },
});

const apiService = {
  post: async (url: string, json = {}, reqConfig = {}) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    if (token) {
      api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    api.defaults.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    const data = json;
    try {
      const response = await api.post(url, data, {
        baseURL: BASE_URL,
        ...reqConfig
      });
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      return err
    }
  }
}

export default apiService
```

and this is my unit test:

```
import apiService from "../api";
import axios from "axios";

jest.mock("axios");
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

describe("apiService", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        mockedAxios.create.mockReturnThis();
    });
    it("should call apiService.post", async () => {
        mockedAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
            Promise.resolve({
                data: {
                    task_id: "123"
                },
                status: 200
            })
        );
        const response: any = await apiService.post("", {
            requester: "example@gmail.com",
            subject: "test",
            description: "test",
            attach: false
        });
        expect(response.data.task_id).toEqual("123");
        expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
    });
});
```

this is the error:

[image]

I have tried to comment the api.defaults code, but i got this one:

[image]

can someone help me to solve my problem? Thankyou.

Comment: I would recommend not mocking Axios. It's a complex API you don't own. Use something like MSW or Nock to assert on the actual requests being made, or test at the integration level.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [axios-mock-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter) package.

E.g.

`api.ts`:

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;


export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json"
  },
});

const apiService = {
  post: async (url: string, json = {}, reqConfig = {}) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    if (token) {
      api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    api.defaults.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    const data = json;
    try {
      const response = await api.post(url, data, {
        baseURL: BASE_URL,
        ...reqConfig
      });
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      return err
    }
  }
}

export default apiService
```

`api.test.ts`:

```
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import apiService, { api } from "./api";

describe("apiService", () => {
  let mock: InstanceType<typeof MockAdapter>;
  beforeAll(() => {
    mock = new MockAdapter(api)
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    mock.restore();
  })
  it("should call apiService.post", async () => {
    mock.onPost('').reply(200, {
      task_id: "123"
    })
    const response = await apiService.post("", {
      requester: "example@gmail.com",
      subject: "test",
      description: "test",
      attach: false
    });
    console.log(response);
    expect(response.data.task_id).toEqual("123");
    expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76183702/api.test.ts (15.588 s)
  apiService
    ✓ should call apiService.post (22 ms)

  console.log
    {
      status: 200,
      data: { task_id: '123' },
      headers: undefined,
      config: {
        url: '',
        method: 'post',
        data: '{"requester":"example@gmail.com","subject":"test","description":"test","attach":false}',
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
        transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
        timeout: 10000,
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        maxBodyLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
      },
      request: { responseURL: '' }
    }

      at stackoverflow/76183702/api.test.ts:19:13

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        16.529 s, estimated 18 s
```